# Format returned date from WooCommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce

This returns the expiry date of a WooCommerce subscription: 
`WC_Subscriptions_Product::get_expiration_date( $product )`
in this format: 
`2017-07-26 20:46:05`.

But I'd like to reformat it so it reads: `26/07/2017`

What is the best way to do this? Can I do it with [createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)?